# Java Scene Builder 2.0, Tab2 is switch to Tab1 in editor?

Tags: java, javafx, components, hierarchy, scenebuilder

picture1: [image: Tab1] picture2: [image]

picture3: [image]

Note: Button1 is in Tab1 and Button2 is in Tab2

In Java Scene Builder 2.0 Editor i added 2 tab on my hierarchy.

When i click the Button2 for edit (in picture1) then the Editor switch to tab1 (in picture1)

Button2 is in Tab2 but when i click it then tab switch to tab1 why?

Is this a bug in Scene Builder 2.0? or am i set wrong the hierarchy (in picture3)?

Comment: Got the same problems with editing elements in tabs as well. The hierarchy looks fine to me from what makes sense.

Comment: @skombijohn i think this is a bug or a version conflict. I still not solved it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 21.03.2014 "Scene Builder" release is fixed this bug.